# JSF Expired ViewScope issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, tomcat6, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I am using JSF2.2 & Tomcat 6.0.35.
I have an application, where we display & edit user details.
I am sending ajax request to do some processing on change of each input for edit details & updating the form.

When i try to change any input after a long idle time (after 30 mins),
I am getting NullPointerException from Managed Bean instance variable.
Is it the server has cleaned the instantiations that are idle for a long time, something that the client-browser doesn’t know ?

Here is the code.

### commonTemplate.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
<title> VSP </title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vsp.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery("#designForm :input[type='text']:enabled:not([readonly='readonly'])").live('change', function(){
    var componentId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    validateInputData(componentId);
    var validForm = (jQuery(".errorMsg").length == 0) ? true : false;
    if(validForm){
        jQuery("#submitDesignForm").click();
    }
}); 
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="commonHeader">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="commonBodyContent">
            <h:form id="designForm" prependId="false" autocomplete="off">
                Common Body Content.
            <h:commandLink id="submitDesignForm" style="display:none;"> 
                <f:ajax execute="@form" 
                        render="@form"
                        listener="#{designBean.processDetails}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>           
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ui:insert name="commonFooter">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

### showDetails.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>#{designBean.person.name}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>#{designBean.person.age}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>#{designBean.person.email}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nationality</td>
                <td>#{designBean.person.nation}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date-Of-Birth</td>
                <td>#{designBean.person.dob}</td>
            </tr>
        .........;
        ..........;
        </table>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

editDetails.xhtml
------------------
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{designBean.person.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{designBean.person.age}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{designBean.person.email}" disabled="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nationality</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{designBean.person.nation}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date-Of-Birth</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{designBean.person.dob}" /></td>
            </tr>
        .........;
        ..........;
        </table>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
        <param-value>_</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.disableUnicodeEscaping</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/viewExpired.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
        <location>/systemUnavailable.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/invalidAccess.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/notFound.faces</location>
    </error-page>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

### DesignBean

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="designBean")
public class DesignBean implements Serializable{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;

    @ManagedProperty("#{userService}")
    private UserService userService; // This is an application scoped managed bean with eager true.

    private Person person;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean(){
        System.out.println("DesignBean created!");
        person = new Person();
        String userEmail = userBean.getUserEmail();
        if(userEmail!=null && !userEmail.isEmpty()){
            person = userService.getUserDetails(userEmail);
        }
    }

    public void processDetails(){
        person.setLastUpdateTime(new Date()); // Getting NPE here, person object is null after long idle time.
        userService.updateUser(person);
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }

    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person){
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Person getPerson(){
        return person;
    }

}
```

### Person

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;
    private String nation;
    private String dob;
    private Date lastUpdateTime;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNation() {
        return nation;
    }

    public void setNation(String nation) {
        this.nation = nation;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateTime(Date lastUpdateTime){
        this.lastUpdateTime = lastUpdateTime;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdateTime(){
        return lastUpdateTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which is the exception trace you're getting?

Comment: I am getting NullPointerException from DesignBean#processDetails() method.
person.setLastUpdateTime(new Date()); // Getting NPE here, person object is null after long idle time.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for setting the state saving method to the client in your web.xml? Also it seems imposible for the person property to be lost this way. The only chance for that is the entire `DesignBean` being rebuilt but without calling `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: The reason for using client side is we cannot use session sharing.
And i tried adding some logs into @PostConstruct and in a default constructor too. But the logs are not printed(i.e. it is not creating any new instance of that bean).

Comment: If the bean instance remains to be the same, there's only one choice: the property is being set to null at some point in your code.

Comment: I am sure that no where it is set to null.

Comment: I just realised you're using jsf 2.2 over tomcat 6, while it's designed to work in a servlet 3 container.. Even though don't know if related with the problem. Anyway, try to reproduce the problem in a test project, minimizing configuration. That's the only way you have to see what's going on.